# Addition of Strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6

**The task**
is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-strings/)

> Given two non-negative integers num1 and num2 represented as string,
>   return the sum of num1 and num2.
>
> **Note**:
>
> - The length of both num1 and num2 is < 5100.
> - Both num1 and num2 contains only digits 0-9.
> - Both num1 and num2 does not contain any leading zero.
> - You must not use any built-in BigInteger library or convert the inputs
>     to integer directly.

**My solution 1**

```
/**
 * @param {string} num1
 * @param {string} num2
 * @return {string}
 */
var addStrings = function(num1, num2) {
  let result = '';
  let carry = 0;
  const LEN1 = num1.length - 1;
  const LEN2 =  num2.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0, L = Math.max(LEN1, LEN2); i <= L; i++ ) {
    const numb1 = num1[LEN1 - i] ? num1[LEN1 - i] | 0 : 0;
    const numb2 = num2[LEN2 - i] ? num2[LEN2 - i] | 0 : 0;

    const tmp = numb1 + numb2 + carry;
    carry = tmp > 9 ? 1 : 0;
    result = `${tmp % 10}${result}`;
  }
  return carry > 0 ? 1 + result : result;
};
```

**My solution 2**

```
/**
 * @param {string} num1
 * @param {string} num2
 * @return {string}
 */
var addStrings = function(num1, num2) {
  let result = '';
  let carry = i = 0;
  const LEN1 = num1.length - 1;
  const LEN2 =  num2.length - 1;

  while(num1[LEN1 - i] || num2[LEN2 - i]) {
    const numb1 = num1[LEN1 - i] ? num1[LEN1 - i] | 0 : 0;
    const numb2 = num2[LEN2 - i] ? num2[LEN2 - i] | 0 : 0;
    const tmp = numb1 + numb2 + carry;
    carry = tmp > 9;
    result = tmp % 10 + result;
    i++;
  }
  return carry > 0 ? 1 + result : result;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### WARNING

Never do a double assignment in a variable declaration.

```
"use strict";
let carry = i = 0;  // throws i is not defined
```

Without strict mode there is no error and `i` is then declared in the global scope.

Should be either

```
let carry, i;
carry = i = 0;
```

or

```
let carry = 0, i = 0;
```

or

```
let i = 0, carry = i;
```

### General

You can simplify some of the code.

- Rather than test for a character test the position `num1[LEN1 - i]` can be `(LEN1 - i) >= 0`
- Rather than have `LEN1` and `LEN2` as constants use them as indexes saving the need to subtract `i` each time
- Put the test for the last carry in the while loop to save the need to do the final test on return.
- Shortening the variable name length lets you put the addition in one line. Generally I use `a`, `b` or `A` ,`B` for unspecific maths operations.

### Rewrite

I keep `carry` as a Number, JS optimizers don't like variables changing type. The benefit is tiny but on mass worth keeping in mind.

Moved `tmp` to function scope to keep the inner loop free of tokens (noise)

```
function addStrings(a, b) {
    var la = a.length, lb = b.length, res = "", carry = 0, tmp;
    while (la > 0 || lb > 0 || carry) {
        tmp = (la-- > 0 ? +a[la] : 0) + (lb-- > 0 ? +b[lb] : 0) + carry;
        carry = tmp / 10 | 0;
        res = tmp % 10 + res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more safe to have tmp as a constant the loop?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Safe? There are 7 lines of code!!

Comment: Consistency of style? I’d personally always try to use const instead of car/let. Bứt that’s just my opinion